# Fermat's Notes on Diophantus

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a free online copy of Diophantus' Arithmetica as well as Fermat's Notes on it. After some google searching, I couldn't find any. Thanks for your help!

Edit: English translation please, I'm still learning Latin.

Comment: Try http://www.e-rara.ch/doi/10.3931/e-rara-9423

Comment: In which language? In English see [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59437/is-there-an-english-translation-of-diophantuss-arithmetica-available) for a translation of _Arithmetica_. [This](http://science.larouchepac.com/fermat/Observations%20on%20Diophantus.pdf) claims to be a translation of Fermat's notes, but I cannot attest to its authenticity.

Answer (score 1):

archive.org has several versions. Here's one:

https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.154147

Also note this book in paperback (ISBN-10: 1578987547) can be purchased for around $15 on either Amazon or Abebooks.

Comment: Thanks for the review. I would say, in this case, I could only provide a link. Alternatively, I could of said check archive.org for Heath's Diophantus and make sure it is second edition (1910).

Comment: You are correct---the review queue tends to obfuscate context that would have made that easier to spot.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm new at posting on stackexchange, so it's a good reminder on best practices.